# Merge view corner with its parent's corner

Tags: android, android-imageview, android-relativelayout

I have created a dynamic view by extending Relative layout with corner of some radius which changes dynamically depend on device screen resolution. To this view, am adding image view to top right corner. But both corner's are mismatching which does not look good. Below is the output.

[image: Corner's mismatch image]

Code looks like this.

```
class GridItem extends RelativeLayout {

public GridItem(){
..
...
        LayoutParams count_iv_lp = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        count_iv_lp.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_RIGHT);
        count_iv_lp.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_TOP);
        count_iv_lp.setMargins(0,(int) (-2 * props.mDensity),(int) (-2 * props.mDensity), 0);
        addView(mImageViewCount, count_iv_lp);

//Other views added
}

//Set corner radius
protected void setRadiusAndBGColor(int radius,int color){
        GradientDrawable shape = new GradientDrawable();
        shape.setCornerRadius(radius);
        shape.setColor(color);
        setBackgroundDrawable(shape);
    }
}
```

Kindly suggest so that image view can merge to its parent's view corner or something like that.